# Jquery ignoring null check if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that adds table rows on button click which appends an number counter per table row addition to the rows id. I have a button click that iterates the # of times based on that counter and then it grabs the id's of an  with the number counter and checks if they have a value.

CODE:

```
$('#showCounter').click(function () {
            for (var i = 1; i < idCounter; i++) {
                if ($('[id$="txtName' + i + '"]').val() !== "" || $('[id$="txtName' + i + '"]').val() !== null) {
                    console.log($('[id$="txtName' + i + '"]').val());
                }
            }
        });
```

So theoritically, it should only console.log when the textbox' has value but right now so for example I have 3 table rows and 1 row has value, it will console.log all 3 rows. The if statement condition seems to have never been met.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: the condition should be `&&`...

Comment: Isn't it the case the blank and null are both falsey?

Comment: @kukkuz Yeah the && worked, stupid mistake.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a field can not be null, it's always a string value .So do like below:-

```
$('#showCounter').click(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i < idCounter; i++) {
        if ($('[id$="txtName' + i + '"]').val() !== "") {
            console.log($('[id$="txtName' + i + '"]').val());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just do:

```
if ($('[id$="txtName' + i + '"]').val()) {
  console.log($('[id$="txtName' + i + '"]').val())
}
```